# Is there any difference between data types and data structures in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define data type in python  ?

Define data structures in python ?

Are list,sets,dictionaries and tuples are data structures or data type in python ?

Comment: I think that you should propose an answer to your own question. Anyway, is this a python specific question, or a `language-agnostic` question?

Comment: Ok, so `python` specific. What do you think a `data structure` is?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-data-type-and-data-structure/

Comment: list,sets,dictionaries and tuples are data structures

Comment: This is actually a great question and should have a clear stackoverflow answer to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2):

In almost every programming language data type simply is the type of data that you would be using.In python we have 6 basic data types they are int,float,complex,bool,string and bytes. where as the datastructures are the collection of data on which tasks can be done efficiently.  It enables easier access and efficient modifications. Data Structures allows you to organize your data in such a way that enables you to store collections of data, relate them and perform operations on them accordingly.
In python DataStructures can be broadly classified into two categories(Well some people don't accept it)
they are
1)Built in - Tuples,Set,Dict,List.
2)User defined- Stacks,Queues,Tree,Graphs etc.
[image: Data structures tree]

Comment: Are Data Structures also Data Types?

Answer (score 0):

##### From my understanding...

## **Data Structures in Python are also data types.**

Why do I think this?

**[The Official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) places `list`s under the data structure section AND immediately calls `list` a data type.**

[image]

Therefore, I believe `list`, `tuple`, `set`, and `dict` data types are also data structures.

From my understanding, **data structures are just data types that can contain multiple data types within them (including the data type of the containing data structure itself).**

Comment: wouldnt be better that the data type are the different way of storing values using instantiation of such data types ?? A data type List is a data-type while the a = list(1,2,3,4,5,6) is an instantiation of such data type ?